XCFramework - dyld[]: Library not loaded
I have created a xcframework, that use another xcframework. Both are contains ios-arm64 and ios-x86_64-simulator.
The script used is from here.
When added xcframework to xcframework - I mark it with Embed & Sign - same, when added final framework to the project.
For Simulator everything works just fine, but for real device I got error Library not loaded:
dyld[15130]: Library not loaded: @rpath/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK
  Referenced from: <77F81D34-B7B1-3261-B746-29D3EEF9353C> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyMobileSDK.framework/MyMobileSDK

  Reason: tried: '/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file),
'/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyMobileSDK.framework/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (code signature in <FB08F3A8-E96E-3E4C-BF7C-7B33D0A73CA7> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyMobileSDK.framework/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/khb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMobileSDK-axgyphxdwdxsnxhlegfwknbnwmmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' (no such file)

Looks like it's found some nested xcframework '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3D9CA89D-DDB3-4563-A43E-7003AEE29AB5/SampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyMobileSDK.framework/Frameworks/NestedMobileSDK.framework/NestedMobileSDK' but it's marked as not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.),
Both xcframeworks are not signed and embedded in target with Embed & Sign option, so I expect that it's ok that this is not signed.
I found similar questions:

here
here
and here (the most similar to my) (maybe this is an answer - but, I believe that there is must be a way to sign that stuff with some workaround)

but it's a bit another reason for failure.
Can someone advice what's done wrong?

looks like the issue here is the way of signing nested xcframework

it would be great if someone down vote for question to know the reason…
